# fish stopped showing prompt after fish_prompt

Tags: fish

I tried modifying the fish prompt as indicated in this page: http://fishshell.com/docs/current/tutorial.html

When I changed my fish_prompt to

```
function fish_prompt
    set_color purple
    date "+%m/%d/%y"
    set_color FF0
    echo (pwd) '>'
    set_color normal
end
```

I noticed my `alt+left` stopped working. Is there something I need to do to enable `alt+left` within `fish_prompt`?

Comment: what does alt-left normally do?

Comment: If you are in a folder like `~/a/b/c` then `alt-left` will go go `~/a/b` and `alt-right` will bring you back to `~/a/b/c`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your prompt, and it looked to me like the directory history was working ok but that it wasn't clear because prompt wasn't being reprinted correctly.

Instead of

```
echo (pwd) '>'
```

try

```
echo -n (pwd) '> '
```

Comment: There's a default `fish_prompt` function, so it seems unlikely.